# Does existence and uniqueness of a classical solution impose uniqueness of weak solutions to a pde?

Tags: probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

I wonder if one knows that there exists a unique classical solution of a pde (for instance: Fokker-Planck equation), is one able to conclude that there isn't any weak solution of the pde, which differs from the classical one? To be more specific:

I'm facing the following Fokker-Planck Equation:

$−∂tg(x,t)−Δg(x,t)−div(g(x,t)b(x,t))=0$ with initial condition $g(x,0)=g0(x)$

and where $g_0$ is a density function and $b:ℝn×(0,T)$ is a continuous, bounded and lipschitz in x vector field. I know from the literature, that there is a classical solution $g∈C2,1(ℝn×(0,T))$ of this equation.

What i know aswell is that there is an absolute continuous probability measure (the law of the stochastic process, which satisfies the corresponding SDE), which satisfies this fokker-planck equation in a distributional sense and as a consequence, the density function of this measure satisfies the equation in a weak sense. I now wonder if this density function is a classical solution, because of the statement given above. Does anyone know if this is true? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if the following is a bit too general or hand-wavy, but hopefully it will be helpful.

The characteristic property of a differential operator that tells you that a weak solution is equivalent to a strong solution is generally called "**regularity**".

Luckily, there are a whole host of theorems for differential operators in which this property is identified, particularly for differential operators classified as [hypoelliptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoelliptic_operator). Examples of hypoelliptic operators include the Laplace operator (responsible for driftless diffusion) and the heat equation operator. Assuming your $b$ is not sufficiently pathological (which you appear to indicate is the case), the Fokker-Planck operator you describe above should fall into this category.

In short, you can be sure that—assuming you don't have initial conditions/$b$ functions that are too "funky", I think—a weak solution you find to your problem will always be a strong solution. Theorems to prove this property tend to be a bit extensive: a good description of this property is given in this [book](https://bookstore.ams.org/mmono-99) by Norio Shimakura. (Unfortunately the classic PDE book by Lawrence Evans doesn't touch on this property very much, if at all.)